# firebase realtime database update inside function cant see parameter React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, parameter-passing

so im trying to pass a parameter from the onPress function into the database.ref().update(parameter here), but the update function cant see the onPress Parameter. here is my code. Can you help me figure out what im doing wrong?

onSubmit(Attribute){
this.setState({
apply:false,
})
const ref = database().ref('Users/Chase/Ivy')

```
  ref.update({Attribute : this.state.inputText}).then(()=> {
      console.log('updated!!!');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

here is the onPress inline function

{(this.state.apply) ?  <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.onSubmit('Class')} title="Apply"/>

Comment: You are not using the parameter for onSubmit, `Attribute`

Comment: i feel like I am its in the ref.update(Attribute: this.state.input text)...which is inside the onSubmit function. when i typed out the code it didnt put it all in the grey box. sorry this is my first question on here im not sure how to format my questions.

Comment: "Attribute" is the name of the key of the object you are creating. You are not using the parameter in that function called Attribute.

Comment: How can I make the key equal the parameter attribute, because when I called the function I want to pass a different key each time. And thanks for the help

Comment: I’ve tried doing .ref(...Atrribute) which it seems works but the syntax gets messed up when I do that

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about how objects work in JS.

```
const fn (param) => {
  const obj = {param: "something"};
  const obj2 = {[param]: "beta"};
  const obj3 = {param};

  console.log(obj, obj2, obj3);
};

fn("carlos");

// Outputs:
// {param: "something"}
// {carlos: "beta"}
// {param: "carlos"}
```